# bind class member funtion to std::function not need check parameters?

Tags: c++, function, bind

why gcc 9.4 not check parameters when bind a class member funtion to a std::function viriable, but check when bind a global function? here is example code, CreateRpcFun has a parameter, but Test member function print doesn't have any other parameters except this, bind print to CreateRpcFun works well, but global funtion print2 cannot, can anybody explain why?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

using CreateRpcFun = std::function<void(const string &)>;

class Test {
public:
  Test() : str_("nihao!") {}

  // bind print to CreateRpcFun passed compile
  void print() { cout << str_ << endl; }

private:
  string str_;
};

class Holder {
public:
  CreateRpcFun CreateRpc;
};

class Other {
public:
  Other(Holder h, string str) : h_(h), str_(str) {}
  void run() { h_.CreateRpc("world!"); }

private:
  Holder h_;
  string str_;
};

void print1(const string &str) { cout << str << endl; }

void print2() { cout << "magic" << endl; }

int main() {
  Test t;
  Holder h;
  h.CreateRpc = std::bind(&Test::print, &t);

  Other o(h, "hhhh");
  o.run();

  h.CreateRpc = &print1;
  h.CreateRpc("test");

  // h.CreateRpc = &print2; // compile error
  // h.CreateRpc("test");
}
```

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges. You don't use `std::bind` uniformly in the examples.

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind): *If some of the arguments that are supplied in the call to `g()` are not matched by any placeholders stored in `g`, the unused arguments are evaluated and discarded.* I *assume* (not sure) it means the definition of `operator()` of the bind result takes variadic arguments (template or not) and by that it will match any `std::function` as long as the return type is correct. Anyway, that's yet another reason why `std::bind` is inferior to lambdas.

Comment: I don't think is comparing apple to orange, I just ask why bind to member function and assign global function to std::function has different way to treat parameters

Comment: Because `std::bind(&Test::print, &t)("test")` compiles, but `print2("test")` doesn't. It's not about member function vs global function, it's about using `std::bind` vs not using `std::bind`. `h.CreateRpc = std::bind(print2);` compiles, too.